# Hadoop : can a mapreduce update the input?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to write the output of a mapreduce directly into the data which was the input of this mapreduce?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean that you need an iterative job, a job that is run multiple times, every time with the input coming from the output of the previous job?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: if you google for "mapreduce iterative jobs" you'll find a lot of tutorials explaining how to do it.

Comment: In these tutorials the output is different form the input (just swaping the input with the output when job iterating).

Comment: but if the output is equal to the input, every new job will have the same input, and therefore will output the same results!

Comment: I would like to not duplicate the data. I guess the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your job does something new, even dealing with the same data (maybe it takes care of the timestamp of execution or it accesses an external service).

You could try to set the same path for both input and output data:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(configuration.get("/path/to/data"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(configuration.get("/path/to/data")));
```

Since the mappers write their data onto a temp directory, it could work (caveat: I never tried to do that!).

Answer (score 0):

As you have mention You dnt want duplicate Data, which seems like you dnt want to perform any Operation/Analysis of data in dfs, where Mapreduce is only used when analyzing data, so in said case, you can read the previous data in mention location repeatedly.

Note: If You are using language like pig/hive, you need to keep a copy/history of previous data as Pig/Hive you to clear the location before/after processing. So history location can be use to call back the same data again. :)